# Physics of a snooker game

Tags: physics

Anyone can point me to any info regarding physics of a snooker game, if possible more about the ball collisions? I would like to make a game and I need some help about the physics.

Comment: I keep thinking about coding a snooker simulators when playing snooker :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a book online about this,

"[Amateur Physics for the Amateur Pool Player](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~howe/poolphysics.pdf)" by Ron Shepard (PDF Link)

I haven't read it but I've heard it's good for game developers.

Answer (score 1):

Carom3D is a great one, they seem to have mastered the physics.  See these links for more info:

http://www.jimloy.com/billiard/phys.htm
http://archive.ncsa.uiuc.edu/Classes/MATH198/townsend/math.html
http://www2.swgc.mun.ca/physics/physlets/billiards.html
http://www.regispetit.com/bil_praa.htm

Good luck!